# Page not found (404) error while searching through search page Raised by: blog.views.blogpost

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-sitemaps

i am unable to search and get 404 error same problem occur in sitemap views for creating static xml file,
it does not return the url for static file and now have this problem with search as it is unable to find search .html gives this Page not found (404) error while searching through search page Raised by: blog.views.blogpost error.

**Search_Form**

```
<form method='GET' action="/blog/search/" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" id="search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2 my-1 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Search **views.py**

```
def search(request):
    myposts = Blogpost.objects.all()
    query = request.GET['search']
    if len(query)>78:
        myposts = Blogpost.objects.none()
    else:
        post_title = Blogpost.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
        posts_content = Blogpost.objects.filter(Q(content__icontains=query))
        posts_slug = Blogpost.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=query))
        myposts = post_title | posts_content | posts_slug
    if myposts.count() == 0:
        messages.warning(request, "No search results found. Please enter again.")
    context = {'myposts': myposts,'query':query}
    return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='bloglist'),
    path('<slug:post>/', views.blogpost, name='blogpost'),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name="contact"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search")
]
```

My **search.html**

```
{% block body %}

<div class="container mt-3">
    <h5> <p> Search Results:</p> </h5>
        {% if myposts|length < 1 %}
        Your Search -<b> {{query}} </b>- did not match any documents please try again. <br>
            <br> Suggestions:
            <ul>
                <li>Make sure that all words are spelled correctly.</li>
                <li>Try more general keywords.</li>
                <li>Try different keywords.</li>
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="container mt-3">
            <div class="row my-2">
        
                {% for post in myposts %}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                            <h3 class="mb-0"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{post.title}}</a></h3>
                            <div class="mb-1 text-muted"></div>
                            <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary"><a>{{post.author}} | {{post.created_on}}</a></strong>
                            <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{post.content|safe}}</p>
                            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                            <img src="/media/{{post.thumbnail}}" class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
                            <title>Placeholder</title></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2%}
            </div>
            <div class="row my-2">
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}</div>
        </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Project **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

from blog.sitemaps import StaticViewsSitemap
from blog.sitemaps import BlogSitemap

sitemaps ={
    'blogpost': BlogSitemap(),
    'static': StaticViewsSitemap(),
}

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('', views.index),
    path('register/', views.registerPage),
    path('login/', views.loginPage),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser),
    path('sitemap.xml/', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
class Blogpost(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES= ( ('0', 'Draft'), ('1', 'Publish'),)


    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=5000, default="")
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', default="")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    featured = models.BooleanField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:blogpost',
        args=[self.slug])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_on',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Can you please include the full view with the `def`, name and the arguments passed and also include your `search.html` completely as well

Comment: @SLDem updated both, kindly have a look plz

Comment: @SLDem together with that now i am unable to search for contact page as well, same error arising for it as well, same static views doesn't generate absolute URL in sitemap xml, i have posted inquiry to that , it seems to be error pertaining to absolute URL

Comment: I don't really see the search `form` anywhere, did you perhaps forgot to include it?

Comment: @SLDem `<form method='GET' action="/blog/search/" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search"
          id="search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2 my-1 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>`

Comment: and where is this form located? In the 'base.html'?

Comment: @SLDem yes " base.html " reside inside navbar

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your **form** to something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'search' %}" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">         
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" arialabel="Search" name="search" id="search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2 my-1 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>       
</form>
```

And your **search** view like this:

```
def search(request):
    myposts = Blogpost.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST'
        query = request.POST.get('search')
        if len(query) > 78:
            myposts = Blogpost.objects.none()
        else:
            myposts = Blogpost.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
            myposts = Blogpost.objects.filter(Q(content__icontains=query))
            myposts = Blogpost.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains=query))
        if myposts.count() == 0:
            messages.warning(request, "No search results found. Please enter again.")
        context = {'myposts': myposts, 'query': query}
    return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

**UPDATE**

So, after going through your **GitHub** repository I saw a couple of issues, first off there is no `urls.py` or `views.py` in your `blog` app, its either not added in the repo or just doesn't exist, which would explain the router not finding any paths for your views, hovewer there is one in the question so I'm not sure whats the issue here, please check again so that the file is in the right directory in the root of your `blog` app folder.

Second off in your main project directory there are files called `urls.py`, `views.py` and `forms.py`, that shouldn't be the case, instead create a seperate app and place them there.

Comment: got an error like the one in Sitemap xml, `NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'search' not found. 'search' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: try removing `namespace='blog'` in your main `urls.py` file where the path for blog urls is defined

Comment: Not  working, same error should it suppose to work with get? shows error at `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'search' %}" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"> ` line

Comment: is your `contact` view working as intended?

Comment: in your main urls instead of this `path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),` write this: `path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),`

Comment: also check if you imported the correct views file, do you perhaps have a github repo of this project?

Comment: No unfortunately i don't have it yet

Comment: create it and share the link here, I don't think we can trace the error with current information here

Comment: Ok, sure i will send link in a while

Comment: be back in about 1 hr mate

Comment: Im looking at your repo but I dont see the main project folder ( the one with `settings.py` ) Did you perhaps forget to include it or accidentally added it to `gitignore`?

Comment: No i added all but in hurry, i did no whats going on. wait i will moved again, i m really sorry these app are part of mywebside (its my main project)

Comment: sorted out, kindly check https://github.com/FazliKhaliq/blog.git

Comment: really appreciate your time, i added it before but dont know why its not their, i added again, plz see

Comment: in your blog `urls.py` you have this line `from .import views` it should be `from . import views` with a spacebar after the `.`

Comment: sorted but still get same error mentioned with above `POST` method "NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'search' not found. 'search' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227108/discussion-between-sldem-and-khaliq-khan).